# How to use float numbers on BusyBox?

Tags: bash, floating-point

I have a little computer with BusyBox, and compiling anything on it is a nightmare.

I want to do something simple like "0,5*2", but can't without additional software.

I tried "expr", "let", and just can't do any operation with float numbers.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Looks like your busybox is old?  Why don't you just use a real calculator or a different computer for doing quick arithmetic problems?

Comment: You're going to have to rebuild the image, and configure dc into the busybox.

Comment: This is ARM computer! Please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

busybox should have awk.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 0.5*2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

`busybox` has `dc` built in.  Here's a link to all of the [documentation](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html).